# Как правильно реализовать функцию/метод принимающий на вход компаратор?

Tags: c++, функции, шаблоны-с++

Вот для примера возьмем функцию сортировки пузырьком, как правильно реализовать в ней компаратор?

```
template<class Iterator>
void BubbleSort(Iterator first, Iterator last) {
    for (Iterator i = first; i < last; i++) {
        for (Iterator j = first; j != last; j++) {
            if (*j > *(j + 1)) {
                std::swap(*j, *(j + 1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Я не понимаю что вы имеете в виду под правильностью...

Answer (score 2):

Примерно так..

```
template<class Iterator, class Comparator>
void BubbleSort(Iterator first, Iterator last, Comparator cmp)
...
       if (cmp(*j,*(j + 1))) {
...
```

Но я бы делал так:

```
template<typename Iter, typename Less>
void BubbleSort(Iter b, Iter e, Less c)
{
    --e;
    for(; b != e; ++b)
        for(Iter k = e, j = k--; j != b; j = k--)
            if (c(*j,*k)) swap(*j,*k);
}
```

Для параметра по умолчанию можно сделать так:

```
template<typename Iter, typename Less>
void BubbleSort(Iter b, Iter e, Less c)
{
    --e;
    for(; b != e; ++b)
        for(Iter k = e, j = k--; j != b; j = k--)
            if (c(*j,*k)) swap(*j,*k);
}

template<typename Iter>
void BubbleSort(Iter b, Iter e)
{
    BubbleSort(b, e, std::less<>());
}
```

Comment: А есть возможность каким то образом из итератора получить сравниваемый тип, чтоб была возможность прописать дефолтное значение для less. Аля typname less = std::les<сравниваемый тип>

Comment: См. дополненный ответ.

Comment: @DenverToha Здесь обошлись без этого типа, но вообще его можно получить как `typename std::iterator_traits<ТипИтератора>::value_type`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Это если итератор стандартный! А если какая-то самописка, в которой *нет* этого `value_type`?... Можно, конечно, поиграться с `decltype(*a)` или чем-то похожим, только вот что-то я не очень представляю, как само объявление шаблона при этом записать...

Comment: Мне кажется, если написал итератор без `value_type` и прочих, сам виноват. А в С++20, похоже, [`iterator_traits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits) научился сам угадывать эти тайпдефы, если их нет.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat OK, а как вы предлагаете этим воспользоваться? это не сарказм, если что — просто как реально записать такую шаблонную функцию? у меня что-то не очень получается...

Comment: Воспользоваться - в смысле передать аргумент в `less`, как автор вопроса хотел? Что-то вроде: `std::less<typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type>()`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Нет, сделать единственную функцию, но с аргументами по умолчанию.

Comment: Тогда так: `template<typename Iter, typename Less = std::less<typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type>>
void BubbleSort(Iter b, Iter e, Less c = {})`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Сенкс! где ж я вчера ошибся? Вроде примерно так и делал (не в ответе, для себя)...

Comment: @Harry Может было что-то такое? `template<typename Iter, typename Less> void BubbleSort(Iter b, Iter e, Less c = std::less<...>())` Это то, что я попробовал в первую очередь, но не сработало...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Похоже на то. В любом случае, спасибо! И все же интересно, а можно ли выкрутиться, не имея `iterator_traits`...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130376/discussion-between-harry-and-holyblackcat).